# unifromly continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Recentlly, I recall that given a continuous function $f(x)$ on a compact set of $\mathbb{R}$ we get that it is uniformly continuous, that is any  finite union of compact set of $R$ ,f is unifromly continuous I have a question that why this result cannot be extend to the R ,I have the example of $y=x$ and $y=x^2$ can any one give me some if and only if condition?

Comment: Do you mean, what conditions should be more for a continous function to be uniformly continous on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x^2$ is a good example. The function is continuous, but not uniformly continuous, on $\mathbb R$. The function is, of course, uniformly continuous on any compact subset of $\mathbb R$.

Sadly, to the best of my knowledge, there is no simple condition that would hold if and only if a function is uniformly continuous.